# Reload a web page without hitting the server?

Tags: javascript, html

Using JavaScript, how can I reload a web page without making any request to the server?

Why would I want to do this? I wrote some JavaScript that draws a picture on the page, and I want the JavaScript to run in a loop. That is:

1. Load the page
2. Draw the picture
3. Re-load the page
4. Draw the picture again

But since I know the JavaScript is the same every time I don't want to hit the server in step (3) – plus I want the page to work offline.

I realize I could write some kind of loop to re-run the JavaScript painting without reloading the entire page, but then I'd have to worry about it properly cleaning up after itself and not somehow taking up a ton of memory as this thing runs for hours. It just seems simpler to reload the entire JavaScript environment every time the picture gets painted.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? And what kind of Picture is it, Kanvas?

Comment: Don't reload the page, just clear the picture and re-draw. Won't that be enough?

Comment: Usually, refreshing the page will simply send a message to the server asking for the page, and then the server replies with a status code that signals the browser that there have been no changes since the last time your browser loaded the page, so your browser just opens the page from the cache. This is really quite unnecessary to do.

Comment: But he wants to use the Page offline, as he said.

Comment: I realize I don't have to reload the page, but trusting the same JS environment to run in a loop for 10 hours seems bad, especially when reloading works perfectly

Comment: First, you must put the page into the browser cache by HTTP-header..

Comment: Is this some kind of a dashboard type of thing? It's not common javascript to run for hours. Perhaps you could monitor user activity and hold the loop until user comes back unless you have some other reason to run for hours.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reload your page from the cache:

```
document.location.reload(false)
```

the parameter states if you want to reload from the Server:

> False: Load from cache
>   True: Force load from Server

For more information about this, klick [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0320__Location/Locationreloadfalsetoreloadfromthecache.htm)

Comment: The false is the default value of argument. The short version would be   `location.reload();`

Comment: Yes but I prefer to go sure, just IF they changed the default value ;D

Comment: I don't think this prevents hitting the server any more than loading the page normally.

Comment: this hits the server w a 304 or something